# Configure nginx to serve manifest.json

Tags: nginx, progressive-web-apps

How should `nginx` be configured in order to serve a `manifest.json` from the root folder of my app?

I have added an entry in `mime.types`:

```
 application/x-web-app-manifest+json     webapp;
```

and since I use json I have added a location entry in my sites-enabled configuration:

```
location /manifest.json {
    default_type application/x-web-app-manifest+json;
}
```

but my `manifest.json` is still not served correctly.

any idea what did I miss or what should I configure differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually my configuration above is correct, my problem was the cache on my phone ;)

Since I already had accessed my PWA before making the corrections in my nginx, my `manifest.json` was cached with a bad content

Clearing the Google Chrome cache on my Android phone and trying again, of course after having applied my configuration and restarted `nginx` solve my issue

Answer (score -1):

I use nginx as part of a progressive web app and I have not changed the configuration of the server at all for the manifest file.

The requirement fro deploying it (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest) among others) is to refer to the manifest file in your html head like this:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

Is there some more information you can share about your problem?

Comment: thx for your answer and time @IanC I already had this in my index.html. The problem was linked to the cache of my phone which I had to clean after having modified my nginx config. Again thx!

Comment: Glad you found the answer - I have had to clear the Chrome cache many times during development!